# Compare two tables with same column name but with aggregate

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate

I am trying to achieve this.

```
TBL 1  
PK   AK   TOT1   TOT2  
1    1    100    100  
2    2    200    200


TBL 2  
PK   AK   TOT1   TOT2  
1    1     50     50  
2    1     50     50  
3    2     100    100  
4    2     50     50
```

My main table is `TBL1`, and is connected with `AK` 
first, I need to sum all `TBL2`'s AK then compare it to
`TBL1`.

I.E.
     `TBL1.AK(1).TOT1 = 100  == TBL2.AK(1).sum(TOT1) = 100`
which is correct
     `TBL1.AK(2).TOT2 = 200  == TBL2.AK(2).sum(TOT2) = 150`
which is wrong.

I need to get return the not equal columns

```
Return TBL  
PK   AK   TBL1.TOT1   TBL2.TOT2  
2    2     200         150 

--Assumed that TBL2 is already totaled.
```

I already tried this:

```
Select AK, SUM(t1.TOT1), SUM(t2.TOT2)  
FROM TBL1 t1  
JOIN TBL2 t2  
ON t1.AK = t2.AK  
GROUP BY t1.AK  
WHERE t1.TOT1 IS NOT t2.TOT2 ....
```

It returns `t1.AK` and summed of `t2.TOT1` and `t2.TOT2`
but not the `t1.TOT1` and `t1.TOT2`.

Update :
I already tried this as of now
`SELECT t1.AK,  sum(t2.TOT1)
FROM TBL1 t1
JOIN TBL t2
ON t1.AK = t2.AK
GROUP BY t1.AK
HAVING t1.TOT1 <> sum(t2.TOT1)`

It returns me 
"00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression""

Comment: Are you using *mysql* or *Oracle*? Please correct your tags

Comment: @hawk, sorry sir. I am using Oracle. I accidentally clickedd mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate before doing the join:

```
Select t1.AK, t1.TOT1, t2.TOT2
FROM TBL1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ak, SUM(TOT2) as TOT2
      FROM TBL2 t2  
      GROUP BY ak
     ) t2
     ON t1.AK = t2.AK
WHERE t1.TOT1 <> t2.TOT2 OR t2.TOT2 IS NULL;
```

Edit:Added t2. at last line to remove column ambiguity

Comment: I have a follow up on this. On my TBL1, I have some AKs that is not present on the TBL2.AK. I need to display them as well. I did this. [FULL OUTER JOIN] and [WHERE t1.TOT = NULL]; but no luck.

Comment: @MaCheeNeraid . . . That involves a left join and some additional comparison logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH table1 AS (SELECT 1 AS ak, 100 AS tot1, 100 AS tot2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2 AS ak, 200 AS tot1, 200 AS tot2 FROM dual  ),
         table2 AS (SELECT 1 AS ak, 50 AS tot1, 50 AS tot2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 1 AS ak, 50 AS tot1, 50 AS tot2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 AS ak, 100 AS tot1, 100 AS tot2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 AS ak, 50 AS tot1, 50 AS tot2 FROM dual )


SELECT table1.ak, table1.tot1, z.tot1 
FROM table1 JOIN
(SELECT table2.ak ak, sum(table2.tot1) tot1, sum(table2.tot2) tot2
FROM table2
GROUP By table2.ak) z ON table1.ak = z.ak
WHERE   table1.tot1 <> z.tot1 
 AND    table1.tot2 <> z.tot2;
```